# "Cannot import name *x* " when making a multi-file program

Tags: python

Trying to make a multi-file program and I am having importing issues with the files. I'm getting an `ImportError: cannot import name 'number_guess'` on the line

```
from numberguesser import number_guess
```

in the main file.

**Main File**

```
from numberguesser import number_guess


def main_menu():

...
```

**Other File**

```
from main import main_menu


def number_guess():

...
```

**Error if it helps**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkS4Z.jpg

If you need to see more of the code, please ask as I am new to posting here.

Comment: You have a circular dependency. Why do both files need to import each other?

Comment: Because I run the function from one file from the main one and then once the function has run, it runs the main file again with the menu.

Comment: That shouldn't be a reason for them to both need to import each other. You should manage that completely from main, calling number_guess from there.

Comment: Thanks for the help!